# Differentiate between elements by CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs

I have made a code to create elements, each of which responds to the `touchstart` event and later in the code I can drag them around the screen. What I would like is to differentiate between different elements based on CSS class they have. All elements have the `DRAG_CSS_SELECTOR` class, but some also have a `MOVE` class or a `ROTATE` class as well.

```
<div class="drag_rotate drag_css_selector"></div>
<div class="drag_move drag_css_selector"></div>
```

However I can't find a way to write in code which element is which. They are all just elements. I have tried:

```
if (this.el.hasClassName(".drag_move")){
this.el = this.elMo;
}
```

But this has no results

```
function DragController(){
  var dragElements = document.querySelectorAll(DRAG_CSS_SELECTOR),
      dragElementsLength = dragElements.length;

  for (var i = dragElementsLength - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    new DragController(dragElements[i]);    
  };
};

function DragController(element){
 this.el = element;
  this.el.addEventListener(START_EVENT, this, false);

  this.elRo = element;
  this.elMo = element;
};
```

Comment: OK, thank you. Not sure I understand the edits.

Answer (score 0):

What are your constants?

With the info given, the only thing I can see wrong is how you're using `hasClassName`. It doesn't take in a selector string - just the string name of the class you're checking.

```
if (this.el.hasClassName("drag_move")){
    this.el = this.elMo;
}
```